ImageMagick: Combine multiple static static gifs with a randomly placed animated gif and preserve the animation
I have many groups of gif images and in each group one of the images is an animated gif. I'm using ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_6 on Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP 8.2.12.
For each group I want to take the images and stack them together into a single gif, preserving the gif animation of whichever image layer is derived from the animated gif. The animated image layer is not in the same position in each group and the animations each have a different number of frames.
This example command correctly layers the images into a single static gif.
convert img1.gif img2.gif img3.gif img4.gif -coalesce -gravity center -background none -compose over -layers merge -layers optimize final.gif
Do you know how I can produce the result pictured in expected.gif below? Thank you.
Example assets
img1.gif

img2.gif

img3.gif

img4.gif

final.gif

expected.gif


Please read about [mcve] and then click [edit] and update your question with your GIFs (animated and static) and an indication of what the expected result is.

Thank you @MarkSetchell - I've updated the post to include the individual assets, actual result of the example command, and an example of expected result.

In Imagemagick your need to use -layers composite to combine them as follows (in Unix syntax), but first flatten img1, img2, img4 into one image. Note the NULL: operator that separates the flattened image and the animated image
magick \
\( img1.gif img2.gif -flatten img4.gif -flatten \) \
NULL: \
\( img3.gif -coalesce \) \
-compose over -layers composite x.gif

For Windows, remove the \ from the parentheses and change the end of line character \ to ^

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#composite
If you want green over red, then try
convert \
\( img1.gif img2.gif -flatten \) \
NULL: \
\( img3.gif -coalesce \) \
-compose over -layers composite \
NULL: \
img4.gif -compose over -layers composite y.gif


That seems to work for me.

Very close, but I think img4.gif (the green one) needs to be above the moving red one.

Then swap the order of img4 and img2.

@fmw42 MarkSetchell is correct. The animated img3.gif needs to be under the green img4.gif, not on top. I've tried your suggestion to swap the order of img4 and img2 but the result was the same (img3.gif incorrectly on top). Thank you.

@Trae I have edited my answer. I believe the change now conforms to your expected output. I added -flatten after img2 to flatten the red first, then the old -flatten will flatten the green over the red.

@Trae Strange it was there at one time. Perhaps I forgot to save it. I changed it again.  There should be two -flatten commands.  Look again.

It is odd that the original did not work. -flatten should take the images in order. But I tried that and it did not work. So I added a flatten after each pair of images

@fmw42 Thank you. With the most recent command this is the resulting x.gif that I am getting on Ubuntu with ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_6: https://i.imgur.com/trh3Wfp.gif

@Trae I would suggest that you upgrade. That version must have a bug. (I presume you changed magick to convert, correct?)

@Trae I just tried with 6.9.13-14 and it works fine. You could try the portable version called magick at https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php if your version is the latest from your Ubuntu distribution.  (Sorry, I cannot get your version to install for me. It is too old for my delegates)

@fmw42 Thank you. It's on shared hosting where I can't upgrade it but I'll look more into the standalone version you've recommended.

You could try Mark Setchell's latest version. You may want to put img3 at the end to avoid green overlaying the red square.

Thank you. Green overlaying the red square is a requirement though.

@Trae If you want green over red, see my edit in my answer where I added new code and output. If that still does not work properly for you, then try Mark Setchell's approach

@fmw42 Thank you. I was able to get IM 7.0.10-43 installed locally and your latest update is working great. I really appreciate the help. I will award the bounty tomorrow once I'm allowed.

I did not know there was a bounty.

Thanks very much for the bounty. I was not expecting that.

I would do it like this because img3.gif has 5 frames:
for ((f=0;f<5;f++)) ; do
   magick img1.gif img2.gif img3.gif[$f] img4.gif -flatten miff:-
done | magick -loop 0 miff:- anim.gif



That puts the green over the red square.  Is that what is asked?. It also reads img1, img2 and im4 5 times, once for each frame of img3.

Interesting approach - thank you. Not all of my animations have the same number of frames. Is there a way for it to support a variable/dynamic number of frames?

I've got fwm42's latest solution working now and have marked it as the accepted answer. Thank you again for the alternative approach though.
